# sequelize special methods/mixins not working

Tags: sequelize.js, associations

i am trying to use special methods fooinstance.addbar() in a many to many association from sequelize but it is not working.

```
UserModel.belongsToMany(ChannelModel, {as: "User", foreignKey: "UserId", through: "channelKey"});
ChannelModel.belongsToMany(UserModel,{as: "Channel", foreignKey: "ChannelId", through: "channelKey"});
```

this is my association between the two models.

```
router.post('/adduser/:id', async (req, res) => {
const {userName} = req.body.user

try {
const currentChannel = models.ChannelModel.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id
    }
})
const addUserToChannel = models.UserModel.findOne({
    where: {
        userName: userName
    }
})
    const addUserName = await currentChannel.addUser(addUserToChannel)
    res.status(200).json(addUserName)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({error: err})
}
})
```

when i add a username in postman i get an error in postman but no error on my terminal. I am getting an id and a userName in terminal but i am not adding a user to a channel in pgadmin.

Comment: Show the error, please

Comment: {
    "error": {}
}
i get this error in postman. nothing else

Comment: then add console.log(err) right before `res.status(500).json({error: err})`

Comment: i get this in terminal 
TypeError: addUserToChannel.addUser is not a function. is there something i have to import to use the special mixins?

Comment: Make sure `models.ChannelModel` has all  associations and output to console `currentChannel` to see what methods it has

Comment: im sorry but how would i go about checking this. btw i see you answer all sequelize tagged questions thanks for helping us noobies out

Comment: Look at `associations` prop in `models.ChannelModel`

Comment: found the issue... i didnt add await on the findOne methods. easy fix but thanks for the help :)